# Plot graph based on struct data (C)

Tags: c, plot, struct

I'm building a memory allocating simulator in C. I did implement three algorithms: First-Fit, Best-Fit and Worst-Fit.

For every clock cycle (just a int counter started in 0), I collect information about % of memory used, how many process are waiting, etc. All information is stored in a list of metrics, there is one list per algorithm(ff,bf,wf) METRICS m*[3] (index 0 take you to the ff list of metrics, index 1 bf list of metrics and so on).

Example of the metric node of the list:

```
typedef struct _metrics {
    int cycle, n_holes, n_waiting, fails;
    float hole_size_med, memory_usage;
    struct _metrics *next;
} METRICS;
```

After that. What I want is to plot a comparative graph between the three algorithms in every single metric stored in the three lists of metrics. What is a simple way to do that?

I really don't speak English, so I'm trying my best...

I'm using Linux Mint.

Comment: Consider using [gnuplot_i](http://ndevilla.free.fr/gnuplot/) if it works on your platform (you should mention your target platform!).

Comment: What he said. Unless you really, really need to include the plotting in your program, have it output data in a format that a well-established plotting utility like `gnuplot` can read.

Comment: I'll gve a try to the gnuplot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use [gnuplot interfaces in ANSI C](http://ndevilla.free.fr/gnuplot/):

> gnuplot is a freely available, command-driven graphical display tool

This is available in Unix, thus Linux Mint would be a match.

Comment: Right, I will try with the gnuplot. Thank you all.